# How to encode Cyrillic characters in JSON

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

I want to read a JSON file containing Cyrillic symbols.

The Cyrillic symbols are represented like `\u123`.

Python converts them to `'\\u123'` instead of the Cyrillic symbol.

For example, the string `"\u0420\u0435\u0433\u0438\u043e\u043d"` should become `"Регион"`, but becomes `"\\u0420\\u0435\\u0433\\u0438\\u043e\\u043d"`.

`encode()` just makes string look like `u"..."` or adds a new `\`.

How do I convert `"\u0420\u0435\u0433\u0438\u043e\u043d"` to `"Регион"`?

Comment: Can you clarify? Those files *are* proper JSON.

Comment: json str: `"\u0420\u0435\u0433\u0438\u043e\u043d"`;
desired: `"Регион"`;
get:`"\\u0420\\u0435\\u0433\\u0438\\u043e\\u043d"`

Comment: After you've deserialized the JSON?

Answer (score 7):

If you want `json` to output a string that has non-ASCII characters in it then you need to pass `ensure_ascii=False` and then encode manually afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `json` module.

```
import json

s = "\u0420\u0435\u0433\u0438\u043e\u043d"

# Generate a json file.
with open('test.json','w',encoding='ascii') as f:
    json.dump(s,f)

# Reading it directly
with open('test.json') as f:
    print(f.read())

# Reading with the json module
with open('test.json',encoding='ascii') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
"\u0420\u0435\u0433\u0438\u043e\u043d"
Регион
```